# strlen() Refuses to Read String from struct hostent *

Tags: c, string, segmentation-fault, strlen

I've been working through a small tutorial on how to build a basic packet sniffer for Linux. I got everything working, and I now want to add IP-to-host mapping.

Everything was working before I added this function:

```
void IPtoHostname(char *ipaddress, char *hostname){
    struct hostent *host;
    in_addr_t ip = inet_addr(ipaddress);
    if (!hostname){
        puts("Can't allocate memory...");
        exit(-1);
    }
    host = gethostbyaddr((char *)&ip, 32, AF_INET);
    hostname = strdup(host->h_name);
}
```

This basically takes a string IP address ("192.168.28.18") *ipaddress* and fills in that IP's hostname ("who.cares.com") into *hostname*.

What happens is that *strlen* **REFUSES** to give me anything (I know how *strdup* works, and I've tested this myself) and segfaults. I've used GDB, and the string ends in a null
character and it isn't NULL.

I've also tested using a raw string assignment with a static struct:

```
void IPtoHostname(char *ipaddress, char *hostname){
    static struct hostent *host;
    in_addr_t ip = inet_addr(ipaddress);
    if (!hostname){
        puts("Can't allocate memory...");
        exit(-1);
    }
    host = gethostbyaddr((char *)&ip, 32, AF_INET);
    hostname = host->h_name;
}
```

And still no dice.

So, what's up with *strlen*?

Comment: The error is probably in the code that is calling this function, as suggested by George's answer. In future post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow... Never fight POSIX. I eventually wrote my function to this:

```
#define MAXHOST 256

char *IPtoHostname(char *ipaddress){
    struct in_addr iaddr;
    inet_pton(AF_INET, ipaddress, &iaddr);
    struct sockaddr_in saddr;
    saddr.sin_family =  AF_INET;
    saddr.sin_addr = iaddr;

    char *hostname = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * MAXHOST);
    if (getnameinfo((struct sockaddr*)&saddr, 32, hostname, MAXHOST, NULL, 0, 0) == -1){
        puts("Cannot reverse engineer IP");
        return;
    }
    return hostname;
}
```

And it works!

Answer (score 4):

Nothing is up with strlen. You need to pass in char **hostname, then set *hostname equal to host->h_name, assuming you're doing your strlen outside of IPToHostName. You're setting a local copy of your hostname pointer.

So you have something like this:

```
char myip[]  = "123.45.67.89";
char *myhost = NULL;

IPToHostname(myip, myhost); /* this sets its own local copy of myhost, which is on the stack */

/* At this point, myhost is still null!! */
```

If you change it to be like the code below it'll probably do what you want.

```
void IPtoHostname(char *ipaddress, char **hostname)
{
    assert(hostname); /* you'll need to include assert.h for this - it'll abort your program in debug mode if hostname is null */

    struct hostent *host;
    in_addr_t ip = inet_addr(ipaddress);
    if (!hostname)
    {
        puts("Can't allocate memory...");
        exit(-1);
    }
    host = gethostbyaddr((char *)&ip, 32, AF_INET);
    *hostname = strdup(host->h_name);
}

char myip[]  = "123.45.67.89";
char *myhost = NULL;

IPtoHostname(myip, &myhost);
```

Comment: Actually, as it turns out, gethostbyaddr was at fault here. Thanks for the tip, though.

Comment: `if (!hostname)` is redundant if you already had `assert(hostname)` (or the assert is redundant, either way)